# How to display errors in overriden FOSUserBundle Registration form?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have overridden the registration .twig files and it works except when the user doesn't enter matching passwords.  How do I display any errors that are thrown by the registration process?

Answer (score 0):

You can render your form errors by using `form_errors` function, like this:

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
{{ form_errors(form.someField) }}
```

You should read this official documentation [How to Customize Form Rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html) to understand in deep how Symfony rendering your form view and how to custom the template as you want.